# Cannot get Angular Filter to display Html Entity

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am trying to display a Green Check Mark for "True" values and a Red Cross for "False values in my MVC View using angular.  Using a filter, I can display the unicode check (u+2713) and cross (u+2718), but they want a "green" check and a "red" cross.  I included angular-sanitize.js on my page and tried to use the ng-bind-html-unsafe directive, when I do the field is blank.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Here is my HTML page:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/app/AccordionCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app/checklist-model.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="AccordionCtrl">

        <table class="table">
            <thead style="background-color:#0e438d; color:white">
                <tr>
                    <td>Company Name</td>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td>State</td>
                    <td>System ID</td>
                    <td>Releast Status</td>
                    <td>Training Tracker</td>
                    <td>SSQ Complete</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="contractor in contractors">
                    <td>{{contractor.vchCompanyName}}</td>
                    <td>{{contractor.vchOprCity}}</td>
                    <td>{{contractor.vchOprStateID}}</td>
                    <td>{{contractor.CompanyID}}</td>
                    <td>{{contractor.ReleaseStatus}}</td>
                    @*<td>{{contractor.TrainingTracker|applyMarks}}</td>*@
                    <td><span ng-bind-html-unsafe="contractor.TrainingTracker | applyMarks"></span></td>
                    <td>{{contractor.SSQComplete|applyMarks}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&#10004</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my filter code in my controller:

```
app.filter("applyMarks", function(){
    return function(input){
        if(input == true){
            //return '\u2713';
            return '&#10004';
        }
        else
        {
            return '\u2718'
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-bind-html-unsafe` has been deprecated since angular 1.2 version.

You need to use `$sce` to sanitize your html.

**Markup**

```
ng-bind-html="contractor.TrainingTracker | applyMarks | trustedhtml"
```

**Code**

```
app.filter('trustedhtml', function($sce) { 
     return $sce.trustAsHtml; 
});
```